# Is my proof about minimal polynomial correct

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-verification, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, minimal-polynomials

I am to prove that the characteristic polynomial and minimal polynomial have same roots. That is, if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of the linear transformation $T$ and if $p(t)$ is the minimal polynomial of $T$ (for finite dimensional vector spaces), then $p(\lambda)=0$. This is of course a very very standard lemma but I have come up with a solution  (?) which I would love to verify.

If it is incorrect, please provide a correct proof along with the explanation as to why it is incorrect. Please use only linear algebra in the answer, not abstract algebra since I have not studied it yet. Thank you!

My proof is as follows:

> Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $T$ with eigenvector $v$. Therefore, $Tv=\lambda Iv$. Taking the polynomial function $p$ on both sides we have,$$p(T)v=p(\lambda I)v$$$$\implies [p(T)-p(\lambda I)]v=0$$
>
> So $p(t)-p(\lambda)$ turns out to be an annihilating polynomial for $T$ and therefore $p(t)|p(t)-p(\lambda)$ which clearly gives $p(\lambda)=0$ as $\lambda$ is a constant but $t$ is a variable.

While I was replying to Slade's comment, I thought of an alternative proof. I think this one is more correct. Here it goes!

> We have that $p(T)v=p(\lambda I)v$ where $v$ is an eigenvector for $\lambda$. Now as $p$ is the minimal polynomial, $p(T)=0$ hence $p(\lambda I)v=0$.
>
> But what is $p(\lambda I)v$? A moment's thought tells us that it is actually $p(\lambda)v$, which is $0$ by previous logic.. But $p(\lambda)$ is a scalar, while $v$ is a NONZERO vector, hence $p(\lambda)=0$

Comment: Looks correct to me.

Comment: Um, is the way I concluded that $p(t)-p(\lambda)$ is an annihilating polynomial just from the fact that $[p(T)-p(\lambda I)]v=0$ correct, where $v$ is an eigenvector for $\lambda$? I am having doubt about that actually.

Comment: Never mind, I thought of an alternative proof which I am going to edit.

Comment: You're right, I see now that there's an issue with that step.

Comment: Please see the edited post now. It should be fine now.

Comment: The first idea is not correct. You can not insure by the previous argument that $p(t)−p(\lambda)$ is an annihilating polynomial for T. However, the second idea is correct.
Actually, you can use the second idea to prove a more general result: If $p(t)$ is a polynomial such that $p(T)=0$, then for every eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $T$, $p(λ)=0$.

Comment: Thank you user. Indeed this shows yet another result: the roots of any annihilating polynomial may not all be the eigenvalues of the matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Your question deals only with the easier part of the statement in your opening sentence, namely that every eigenvalue must be a root of the minimal polynomial. The converse is also true, every root of the minimal polynomial is an eigenvalue, but a different kind of argument is needed here.

The part you treat follows immediately from the general fact that

> $(*)$ for an eigenvector$~v$ of$~T$ for$~\lambda$ and *any* polynomial $P$ one has $P[T](v)=P[\lambda]v$.

Then taking for$~P$ the minimal (or any annihilating) polynomial of$~T$ the left hand side is$~0$, and you can conclude using$~v\neq0$ as you did).

That fact $(*)$ is most easily shown using $T^n(v)=\lambda^nv$ (induction on$~n$) and linearity over the terms of the polynomial$~P$. But other proofs are possible. However your first attempt is wrong: one cannot (in general!) from $A(v)=B(v)$ conclude that $P[A](v)=P[B](v)$. You second attempt is correct. However, it uses that $P[\lambda I]=P[\lambda]I$, which if you think of it is just $(*)$, using the fact that *any* (non-zero) vector is eigenvector of$~\lambda I$ for$~\lambda$. So you need to do that induction/linearity proof anyway.